# std::vector emplace_back vs std::deque push_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stack, queue

I have a set of items, which i push back at the end of the container and pop back. For this purpose,
I'm not using std::stack because std::stack is already using std::deque inside. So I'm using std::vector<> and instead of push_back, I'm using emplace_back as i have multiple arguments.

I would like to know is it worth switching to std::deque to improve performance?

Comment: Is that really a bottleneck? I'd go for the one that most clearly signifies the intent. Also a vector is as cache friendly as you can get which gives it quite a bit of performance as a standard container.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it will improve performance or not will depend greatly on your usage pattern: how much you push, how often you pop, how expensive is element copying (or moving) during vector reallocation and so on and so forth. There's no way to say anything definitive without looking at the specifics. Try it, profile it and see which one works better.

BTW, you can specify which container type `std::stack` will use under the hood. And you also have `std::list` to try.